# Android: How can I avoid copy&paste while programming?

Tags: android, view

A simple example:

```
Dialog d=new Dialog(Activity.this);
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(Activity.this);
TextView textview1=new TextView(Activity.this);
TextView textview2=new TextView(Activity.this);
TextView textview3=new TextView(Activity.this);
TextView textview4=new TextView(Activity.this);
  ......
linearLayout.addView(textview1);
linearLayout.addView(textview2);
linearLayout.addView(textview3);
linearLayout.addView(textview4);
.....
d.setContentView(linearLayout);

d.show();
```

I just use Copy&Paste and change the 1, 2, 3, 4, ... at the end of the view-names, but if there is an OnClickListener and it opens a new dialog after click (and so on), I get huge classes which cointains only copy&paste-code. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Either learn how to use loops or learn how to write OO code?

Comment: Ok, please show me how can I do this example from above in OO code

Comment: For the specific example OO approach is not applicable. Use a loop. OO is applicable where you have multiple classes doing the same or very similar things. See answer from 
vivoconunxino

Answer (score 3, accepted):

what about an array?

```
Dialog d=new Dialog(Activity.this);
LinearLayout linearLayout=new LinearLayout(Activity.this);
int n=5;
TextView[] text_views = new TextView[n];

for(TextView text_view : text_views)
{
 text_view=new TextView(Activity.this);
 linearLayout.addView(text_view);
}

d.setContentView(linearLayout);

d.show();
```